# I'm getting totally wrong String value from the application.yaml file in the Spring Boot app.The value in yaml config is 044525266 and in var 9611958

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, snakeyaml

May be this is because of leading zero?

```
acquiring:
  bic: 044525266
```

in yaml is loaded through

```
   @Autowired
    public AcquiringService(
...
                            @Value("${acquiring.bic}") String bic,
...
)
```

The Spring Boot version is: `2.1.8.RELEASE`

It uses library `org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.23`

[image]

Comment: https://ruudvanasseldonk.com/2023/01/11/the-yaml-document-from-hell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've pointed out, quotes fix the issue. The reason can be found in the [YAML 1.1 spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/).

> **Example 2.19. Integers**
>
> canonical: 12345
> decimal: +12,345
> sexagesimal: 3:25:45
> octal: 014 <<<<<<<
> hexadecimal: 0xC

In YAML 1.2, octals use `0o` instead of `0`.

So `044525266` in octal becomes `9611958` in decimal.

For correct usage is should use quotes

```
acquiring:
  bic: "044525266"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
acquiring:
  bic: "044525266"
```

Quotes did the trick. And I have no idea why, why `String` can't be read just as a `String`?

Comment: String is read as String just fine. However, if you put an octal literal in your YAML, that'll be read as the number it is first, *then* converted to String (in decimal).

Comment: How _normal_ people would know that rather than from facing a related failure?

Comment: @Jorn I would like you to turn your comment to the official answer, it really makes sense.